# Claim mapping "Failed login attempts" in wso2 stops working

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Claim mapping "Failed login attempts" in wso2 stops working after we remove and add the claims using WSDL "`https://[Server]:9443/services/RemoteClaimManagerService.RemoteClaimManagerServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint?wsdl`"

We also observed that, when manually removing and adding claim mapping works as expected.

Please share your thoughts and help me in resolving the issue.